# VBA Pivot table add text if no result

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have 2 macros which I call separately.
The first one selects a pivot table and uses the results in a specific cell to filter pivot table criteria
The second one copies the pivot table results and puts it into a new worksheet

In some instances there is no data in a pivot table. When there is no data I'd like to add text instead of a pivot table with no values. How can this be done?

```
    Sub SelectFields()
Dim a As String
Dim pt As PivotTable

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
a = Worksheets("Selection").Cells(3, 1).Value

For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
With pt.PivotFields("CODE")
.ClearAllFilters
.CurrentPage = a
End With

Next

End Sub
```

Macro 2, the copy code, where I think the new code should say, if the pivot table has no data then "random text"

```
    Sub CopyPivotBody()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim rngBody As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("sheet1")
    Set pt = ws.PivotTables(1)
    Set rngBody = pt.TableRange1
    
    
    rngBody.Copy Sheets("Selection").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
End Sub
```

Thanks,

Comment: Check the value of `rngBody` before copying?

Comment: I've been having a play around and I can't work out how to do this - can you provide any more detail please?

Comment: Do you mean you have a PT but it contains no data? Perhaps you could check the source data.